# Display Content Query in slideshow

Tags: content-query-web-part, blog

I've created sub-site as a Blog site for news and I want to display that news in the home page of the root site as a slide-show. Item's fields that I want to display are: title, rollup image and body.

Comment: Are you very comfortable with JavaScript and CSS?

Comment: css yes, but little bit of JS

Answer (score 2):

You need some decent JavaScript skills to do this.

The Microsoft term to search for is `Display Templates` to rewrite Content Query output with JavaScript into the HTML you want.

See: https://en.share-gate.com/blog/sharepoint-slider-display-template